# NodeJS: change property is server crash

Tags: node.js

When I have this code on client side:

```
socket.emit("requestUsername", {
    value: $( "#inputUsernameg" ).val()
});
```

And this as server side:

```
socket.on('requestUsername', function(username) {
    if (username.value.trim() == '') {
        socket.emit('error', { value: 'error2' });
    }
)};
```

But when I change the client side code to:

```
 socket.emit("requestUsername", {
        trolol: $( "#inputUsernameg" ).val()
    });
```

I will get a server crash:
[image: server crash]

So, if I can crash the server on the client side other people can too, how to secure this?

Comment: **ALWAYS** check user input ...

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(username)`? . If you design you server side code to make it handle all possibilities; users cant make crash your server. Or may be they can. but less possibility. And yes. Check `INPUTS` all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to test the value before trimming :

```
if (!data.value) {
    socket.emit('value is missing);
    return;
}
// rest of your code
```

You could also put your request handling code in a `try` block and emit an error in the `catch` block (a sane code would still check the input).